# Disable Text Selection and Copying

Tags: html, css, copy-paste

I'm trying to disable text selection and disable text copying. I used the css below

```css
.noselect {
 -webkit-touch-callout: none !important;
 -webkit-user-select: none !important;
 -khtml-user-select: none !important;
 -moz-user-select: none !important;
 -ms-user-select: none !important;
 -o-user-select: none !important;
 user-select: none !important;
}
```

```html
<p>Selectable Text below</p>
<p class="noselect">Unselectable Text but when I Ctrl+A and Ctrl+C, it still copies.</p>
<p>Selectable Text above</p>
```

The user can't select the text but on select-all, the user can copy it all. Any thoughts?

Comment: Maybe the bootstrap overrides your css?

Comment: Can you show an example where it doesn't work?

Comment: works fine -- https://jsfiddle.net/hs1j9rnh/

Comment: At others: See my link here. @Tasos Now it doesn't work anymore when I add a text above it: https://jsfiddle.net/hs1j9rnh/1/

Comment: works fine on my tablet, and desktop-- what are you using?

Comment: I guess you are doing it wrong. Did you "Select All", Ctrl+C and then Ctrl+V on a text editor? It appears like it doesn't select but it will "Paste" the middle line successfully. Tried in on Chrome, Safari, Firefox - both in Windows laptop as well as Mac.

Comment: PS: It has nothing to do with bootstrap as I suspected earlier. It was to do with the "noselect" sandwich between text paragraphs. Anyone?

Answer (score 0):

you can prevent the user from clicking `ctrl+a` watch out this snippet

```
$(function(){   
$(document).keydown(function(objEvent) {        
    if (objEvent.ctrlKey) {          
        if (objEvent.keyCode == 65) {                         

            return false;
        }            
    }        
});
```

Comment: there's still an option to copy using right click. I do NOT want to disable right click. Thank you though :)

Comment: you can use `pseudo element`

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/RWWGpK

but he still have inspector :)